# Dúvida TempData C# com MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Eu sei que o `TempData` tem a sua "vida" mantida até que ele seja utilizado na `View`. Porém, se eu fizer em dois controllers diferentes, a mesma identificado do `TempData`, estou matando e sobre escrevendo eles.

Se o usuário estiver usando 2 abas do navegador, pode emitir a mensagem errada.

Então, como posso usar o `TempData` ou outra funcionalidade, para enviar dados de um `Controller` para a `View`, para passar mensagens, sem ter o problema com multi abas. Também não queria passar por URL.

### Dados complementares (Editado)

#### Código

```
using (var db = new Conexao())
{
    var usuario = db.Usuario.Find(id);
    var retorno = EntidadeBaseExt.ValidarRegistro(usuario);                
    if (retorno != "")
    {
        TempData["MsgRetornoError"] = retorno;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return View(usuario);
}
```

#### Problema

Se o usuário estiver utilizando 2 abas, na aba 1 ele busca o id = 1 e na aba 2 ele busca o id = 3, e ambas tem mensagem de retorno com erro.

Pode acontecer da mensagem da aba 2, sobre escrever a mensagem da aba 1, e apresentar a informação errada.

Desta forma eu teria que passar alguma forma para garantir que a aba 1 pegue a sua mensagem e a aba 2 pegue a sua mensagem.

Se eu fazer assim:

`return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { msg = "Teste " + id.ToString() });`

o campo msg fica na url e eu não queria isto.

Comment: Já tentou ViewBag?

Comment: @Ricardo Se utilizar o comando `RedirectToAction` o valor fica nulo. Este é o problema.

Comment: Coloca um exemplo do seu código aí. Aí fica mais fácil de ajudar.

Comment: @Ricardo melhorei a pergunta. Mas você me deu uma ideia, fazer assim: `return RedirectToAction("Msg", "Home", new { id = idMensagem });`, aonde o id vira uma session com os dados que preciso. Desta forma a url fica limpa, e diminui o problema de dados cruzados.

Comment: eu atualizei a resposta, no código que eu coloquei vc pode passar o ID na url para pesquisar e retornar os dados na session, vai funcionar como você quer. Caso tenha resolvido não deixe de marcar a resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos lá, não entendi 100% o que você quer... Vou tentar:

> Eu sei que o TempData tem a sua "vida" mantida até que ele seja
>   utilizado na View. Porém, se eu fizer em dois controllers diferentes,
>   a mesma identificado do TempData, estou matando e sobre escrevendo
>   eles.

Toda vez que entra em uma Action ele executa o código, se estiver incluindo o valor em `TempData["Mensagem"] = "MinhaMensagem";` realmente ele vai sobre escrever.

> Se o usuário estiver usando 2 abas do navegador, pode emitir a
>   mensagem errada.

Cada vez q ele executar uma URL ele executa uma action, o mesmo vale para o `RedirectToAction`, a action que vai receber a requisição será processada e o caso explicado acima de substituição ira ocorrer.

> Então, como posso usar o TempData ou outra funcionalidade, para enviar
>   dados de um Controller para a View, para passar mensagens, sem ter o
>   problema com multi abas. Também não queria passar por URL.

Essa parte não ficou clara sobre o que seria o problema com multi abas. Eu acho que se você usar `session` irá resolver o seu problema, porque o que for colocado dentro da `session` na Action 1 terá o valor mantido quando for direcionado para Action 2 e a view que a Action 2 chamar poderá ter acesso a essa informação.

```js
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            Session["message"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction("About","Home");
            //return View();
        }
```

Nesse código ele vai executar a Action About e a view About pode exibir a session

```
@Session["message"]
```

**Atualização**

```js
        public ActionResult Index(string mensagem)
        {

            Session["message"] = mensagem;
            
            return View();
        }
```

Se você usar session ele vai manter uma mensagem por aba... Passa um código para o controle e retorna na session a mensagem, vai funcionar.